# Invalid app name Django-CMS

Tags: python, django, debian, pip, django-cms

Using Django-CMS 3.0 installation doc on Raspbian with kernel 3.18.7, python3, pip3. When I run

```
djangocms -p . mysite
```

I get:

```
~/django/env$ sudo djangocms -p . mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/djangocms", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('djangocms-installer==0.7.2', 'console_scripts', 'djangocms')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 337, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2280, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1990, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangocms_installer/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from . import config, django, install
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangocms_installer/config/__init__.py", line 101
    sys.stderr.write(u"Project name '%s' is not a valid app name, "
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Note: I am running it from `~/django/env`.

Comment: Is that the full error?

Comment: Missed a single line and I've update the post with it... it's a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python3 doesnt like the unicode helper which DjangoCMS 3 is using:

```
# First of all, check if the project name is valid
if not validate_project(args.project_name):
    sys.stderr.write(u"Project name '%s' is not a valid app name, "
                     u"or it's already defined. "
                     u"Please use only numbers, letters and underscores.\n"
                     % args.project_name)
    sys.exit(3)
```

Those 'u' before the strings are giving synxtax error for python 3. You could fix it straight in that file, check for Django CMS and ask for a fix, or use a lower python's version like 2.7

And it's weird because here it appears DjangoCMS is supported by python3 https://www.djangopackages.com/python3/

Some testing I just did with a python3.2 interpreter:

```
>>> sys.stderr.write(u"Hello ")
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    sys.stderr.write(u"Hello ")
                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> sys.stderr.write("Hello ")
6
Hello >>>
```

Comment: That's what I first thought but trying different names didn't help. In fact, I tried the name that's provided in django-cms 3.0 doc --> mysite. Still same error.

Comment: Oh I see that syntax error, it hasnt anything to do with the project's name, can you, looks like there is a problem with your python version and django cms although I have checked if DjangoCMS is supported by python3 and it's ok. Can you check with python 2.7? or try editing this file /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/djangocms_installer/config/__init__.py and removing the 'u'. I will edit my previous post to make it clearer

Comment: Also check the code is still going inside if not validate_project(args.project_name): so your project's name is still not validated, you should try printing/debugging it

Answer (score 0):

You should update your Python version to 3.3 or 3.4. Neither django CMS nor djangocms-installer support Python 3.2.

As @lapinkoira suggests, the specific issue you are seeing are due to `u''`-prefixes. These have been brought back with Python 3.3, though, to make it easier to support both Python 2.6+ and Python 3.3+ (see also [PEP 414](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0414/))

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that too. Suggestion by @lapinkoira resolve the issue but upgrading to 3.3/3.4 might be a more scalable solution.